# Add message and stay on form after clicking commandButton

Tags: forms, validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have a form with some fields that are validated while processing the form data. It's a kind of a plausibility / consistency check. The check itself is costly, so it should not be performed twice. But it **must** be performed during successful form submission, so it's part of the commandButton's action method in the backing bean.

I think if I use a <f:validator>, it will be performed once for the validation phase and then once again when submission takes place. As I said, that's not desirable.

As far as I understand the docs, it should be sufficient to add a message to one of the form's components in order to stay on the form.

So I've tried

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("comandButtonID", "some message");
```

but it does not stay on the form.

Do I need to do something additional to mark the form as invalid ?

If it matters, the backing bean is request-scoped.

So, here comes the minimal complete example.
OS: Linux
Browser: Chromium
Server: Tomcat 8.0.36
JDK: Oracle-JDK 1.8.0_92
JSF implementation: myfaces 2.1.18 + tomahawk 20-1.1.14

There is one thing I found out during creating this example:
When I set javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE to "Development" and facelets.DEVELOPMENT to "true", and the message is displayed.
With the settings grom the web.xml below, it's not.

web.xml (omitted descriptions)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>
      org.apache.myfaces.NUMBER_OF_VIEWS_IN_SESSION
    </param-name>
    <param-value>20</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <!-- START MyFaces filter -->

  <filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
      org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
      <param-value>100m</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
      <param-value>100k</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- END MyFaces filter -->

  <!-- START MyFaces config -->

    <context-param>
      <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SERIALIZE_STATE_IN_SESSION</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>
      org.apache.myfaces.READONLY_AS_DISABLED_FOR_SELECTS
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>
      org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER
    </param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ADD_RESOURCE_CLASS</param-name>
    <param-value>
      org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.DefaultAddResource
    </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>
      org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_VIRTUAL_PATH
    </param-name>
    <param-value>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- END MyFaces config -->

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>testform.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
              version="2.0">

  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>FormTest</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>FormTest</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>

  <navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
      <from-action>#{FormTest.formAction}</from-action>
      <from-outcome>OK</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/testform_OK.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <!-- I've also tried to remove the second navigation-case -->
    <navigation-case>
      <from-action>#{FormTest.formAction}</from-action>
      <from-outcome>FAIL</from-outcome>
      <to-view-id>/testform.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
  </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

FormTest.java

```
public class FormTest {
  String input;

  public String getInput() {
    return input;
  }

  public void setInput(String input) {
    this.input = input;
  }

  public String formAction() {
    final boolean valid = "ok".equalsIgnoreCase(input);
    if (!valid) {
      final FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("not OK");
      message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("submit", message);
    }
    return valid ? "OK" : "FAIL";
  }
}
```

testform.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

<h:head>
  <title>Test Form</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
  <h:form id="form">
    <h:outputText value="Enter &quot;ok&quot; (case insensitive) to get to the next page."/>
    <br/>
    <h:outputText value="Any other value should give an error message and stay on this page."/>
    <br/>
    <h:inputText id="input" value="#{FormTest.input}"/>
    <br/>
    <h:message id="submitMessage" for="submit"/>
    <t:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{FormTest.formAction}"/>
  </h:form>
</h:body>

</html>
```

testform_OK.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
  <title>Form was submitted</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
  Form was submitted with value &quot;OK&quot;.
</h:body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have not yet added a validator. What I wrote is my understanding of the lifecycle: when I click the submit button, all validation is done and if it fails, the action is never called. if validation succeeds, my action is called. So, if I add a validator that performs my check, and the action method does so too, it will be performed twice. Or is there something I misunderstood ?

Comment: No, it's not theoretically. I have the form and the action method that performs the check and adds the message to the commandButton. And I can see that adding the message is not sufficient to stay on the page. What I have not tested so far is the validator for **this** form. On other forms, I have a validator and I have tested that the action is never called when the validator says "No".

Comment: No, I don't.
The check I'm doing is currently part of the action method. If I add a validator, I would first need to refactor the action method and extract the check, so I could call it from the validator, too.
This is doable, but it would introduce performing the check twice, at least if validation succeeds.

My question is based on the effect I see on this form (not staying on the page although I add a message) and things I saw on other forms (action not called when validation fails).

Comment: Perhaps one more explanation would help: The check is more than a simple check. It also produces some data and (if successful) writes statistics data to the database. Yes, I could refactor it too and divide it in two steps. But this is also additional work and a partial redesign. The project is really old and not so well designed and I've recently taken it over.

Comment: OK, I' will prepare a MCVE. In between, I found an example that worked with JSF 1 and springframework 3.x: 

getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put(AbstractProcessingFilter.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION_KEY, exception);

 It seems I need a replacement for that.